# Can I link an AWS CloudFront distribution to an S3 bucket, and have one folder path direct to an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

(warning, I'm an AWS rookie)
I have an S3 bucket set up for static web page hosting, and an Elastic Beanstalk (php) instance available through an EC2 instance.

What I'd like to do with a CloudFront distribution///

Everything under:
http://(cloudfront_domain)/*
is ditrected to the S3 bucket,

-except-

everything under:
http://(cloudfront_domain)/one_folder/*
is directed to the EC2 instance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Helpful rookie tip: "redirect" is probably not the right word to describe this.  In HTTP, a *redirect* is when the site *tells the browser* to fetch the content elsewhere, from a different URL, and the browser then starts over and makes a second request.  You seem to be asking how to *forward* these specific requests, and yes, this is something CloudFront is quite good at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by adding the EC2 instance as an origin (Use EC2 instance Public DNS) and creating a [Cache Behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesCacheBehavior) with a Path Pattern routing that `/one_folder*` to the EC2 origin.

For more complex routing rules, you can also consider using [Lambda@Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html).